# What does the phrase "if I am anything to go by" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrases

I have come it across in this [program](https://youtu.be/GdGcE_-_T8Y). It's at 1 minute and 18 seconds. Here it is:

> Presenter A: So my question is: what percentage of people in the UK has less than 1000 pounds in savings? Is it a) 5%, b) 15%, c) 30%?
>
> Presenter B: **If I am anything to go by**, I'd say c) 30%.

Comment: It was probably said that way because it's an expression, but "If I am *anyone* to go by" seems more grammatically correct. An alternative form would by "If *my savings* is anything to go by".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"If [x] is anything to go by" means that the subject [x] is an example of the point you are trying to make.

> Presenter A: So my question is: what percentage of people in the UK has less than 1000 pounds in savings? Is it a) 5%, b) 15%, c) 30%?
> Presenter B: If I am anything to go by, I'd say c) 30%.

In your example, Presenter B seems to be implying that he or she has less than £1000 in savings, and that has led them to believe that the percentage would be quite high.

Comment: You are correct, but don't you mean "a high estimate" (i.e., the highest percentage among the choices) in your last sentence?

Comment: Astralbee: Thank you for the helpful answer! Could you please tell me if the phrase "judging from" means the same? For example: "Judging from me I would say 30 %."

Comment: @CanadianYankee You're right. In this case a high percentage is a low number of people with savings.

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope "Judging *by my own savings*" would make more sense than your suggestion.

Comment: How does someone 'know' he is like 30% of the population? Or any other percentage?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: He doesn't. Presenter B is a bit of a dummy, which we could have guessed anyway from the fact that he has such a low level of personal savings. I know the BBC don't pay *that* well, but if you've managed to land yourself a position presenting "Learning English" with them, I'm sure they pay enough for you to make *some* provision for getting by when the license fee becomes "optional" (at some point in the foreseeable future).

Comment: I would imagine that the presenter is being humorously self-deprecating.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey maybe because there are two people in the conversation, and since she knows she doesn't save as much as she should, at least 50% of the people in that conversation are not saving that much, and she is projecting that estimation onto the entire population.